# Passing a the variable to my erb code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, erb

In my ruby on rails application I have a view that lists some recods.

I also have some filters on the page with javascript onclick events on them that retrieve their ids and filters the records on the page.

The ids of the buttons clicked are stored in a javascript variable

```
var selected = [];
```

In my index.html.erb I would like to use the value of my selected[] array to retrieve data from the database and filter the index page.

I saw in other posts that we cannot pass javascript variables to erb code since the the latter is executed in the server.

How do I pass my selected ids to my erb function using ajax or another way?

```
    <% Post.recent(**selected**).each do |post| %>
       .....
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this is by submitting a form with the `selected` as part of the `params` hash, and then I suppose you could do it.

For example

`<input type='hidden' value="selected['cool', 'fun', 'happy', 'ruby']" />`

this would then be accessible in your controller as `params[:selected]`, and from there you could make it an instance variable as in

```
@selected = params[:selected]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am not using a form and I'm not using a controller. It's just buttons on the page with events hiding/showing elements.